# Querying data for S-Curve Purposes

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I am trying to make an S-curve analysis using data from oracle that span from specified date range,

my query looks like this,

```
    SELECT LEVEL WEEK_NUM_INCR,
           TO_CHAR (start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7, 'WW') WEEK_POSITION,
           /* WEEK POSITION FOR THE WHOLE YEAR */
           TO_CHAR (start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7, 'MM/DD/YYYY') START_WEEK_DATE,
           TO_CHAR (start_date + (LEVEL) * 7, 'MM/DD/YYYY') END_WEEK_DATE,
           (SELECT SUM (ONSITE_UPD_QTY)
              FROM DTL_ERC_UPD@WELTES_SITEMON_LINK
             WHERE     UPD_DATE BETWEEN RS.start_date AND RS.end_date
                   AND PROJECT_NAME IN (SELECT PROJECT_NAME
                                          FROM PROJECT
                                         WHERE PROJECT_NO = RS.JOB_NAME))
              ONSITEQTY
      FROM (SELECT PS.PROJECT_START_DT start_date,
                   PS.JOB_NAME JOB_NAME,
                   PS.PROJECT_END_DT end_date
              FROM PROJECT_SPAN PS
             WHERE PS.JOB_NAME = 'W-14026') RS
CONNECT BY start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 < end_date;
```

So on the PROJECT_SPAN table the content is,

```
PROJECT_START_DT PROJECT_END_DT JOB_NAME
1/1/2015         2/1/2015       W-14026
```

And on the DTL_ERC_UPD@WELTES_SITEMON_LINK the content is,

```
PROJECT_NAME   UPD_DATE              ONSITE_UPD_QTY
---------------------------------------------------
SMSMILLHOUSE   2/5/2015 12:00:01 AM  2
SMSSUGARWHOUSE 2/5/2015 12:00:01 AM  2
SMSMILLHOUSE   2/4/2015 12:00:01 AM  4
SMSMILLHOUSE   2/4/2015 12:00:01 AM  6
IGGMILLHOUSE   2/4/2015 12:00:01 AM  4
IGGMILLHOUSE   2/4/2015 12:00:01 AM  6
```

So the connected table is PROJECT that contains,

```
PROJECT_NO PROJECT_NAME
-----------------------
W-14026    SMSMILLHOUSE
W-14026    SMSSUGARWHOUSE
```

When i query that sql i get this only

```
WEEK_NUM_INCR   WEEK_POSITION   START_WEEK_DATE END_WEEK_DATE   ONSITEQTY
1.00            01              01/01/2015      01/08/2015  
2.00            02              01/08/2015      01/15/2015  
3.00            03              01/15/2015      01/22/2015  
4.00            04              01/22/2015      01/29/2015  
5.00            05              01/29/2015      02/05/2015
```

The intended output is

```
WEEK_NUM_INCR   WEEK_POSITION   START_WEEK_DATE END_WEEK_DATE   ONSITEQTY
    1.00            01              01/01/2015      01/08/2015  0
    2.00            02              01/08/2015      01/15/2015  0
    3.00            03              01/15/2015      01/22/2015  0
    4.00            04              01/22/2015      01/29/2015  0
    5.00            05              01/29/2015      02/05/2015  14
```

Please help me what am i missing with my query ???

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect ONSITEQTY to be 14 for WEEK_NUM_INCR = 5?

DTL_ERC_UPD contains two rows for 4th February and two rows for 5th (the rest two rows don't suit due to PROJECT_NAME limitation).

**START_DATE** and **END_DATE** in PROJECT_SPAN include only January - there are no rows that suit "between" condition. It seems like you expect DTL_ERC_UPD to be limited between **START_WEEK_DATE** and **END_WEEK_DATE**. If that's the case then you need to wrap your query by one more select like this:

```
with PROJECT as (
  select 'W-14026' as PROJECT_NO, 'SMSMILLHOUSE' as PROJECT_NAME from dual union all
  select 'W-14026', 'SMSSUGARWHOUSE' from dual
),
DTL_ERC_UPD as (
  select 'SMSMILLHOUSE' as PROJECT_NAME, to_date( '2/5/2015 12:00:01 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM' ) as UPD_DATE, 2 as ONSITE_UPD_QTY from dual union all
  select 'SMSSUGARWHOUSE', to_date( '2/5/2015 12:00:01 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM' ), 2 from dual union all
  select 'SMSMILLHOUSE', to_date( '2/4/2015 12:00:01 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM' ), 4 from dual union all
  select 'SMSMILLHOUSE', to_date( '2/4/2015 12:00:01 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM' ), 6 from dual union all
  select 'IGGMILLHOUSE', to_date( '2/4/2015 12:00:01 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM' ), 4 from dual union all
  select 'IGGMILLHOUSE', to_date( '2/4/2015 12:00:01 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM' ), 6 from dual
),
PROJECT_SPAN as (
  select to_date( '1/1/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) as PROJECT_START_DT, to_date( '2/1/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) as PROJECT_END_DT, 'W-14026' as JOB_NAME from dual
)
select WEEK_NUM_INCR,
       TO_CHAR (START_WEEK_DATE, 'WW') WEEK_POSITION,
       /* WEEK POSITION FOR THE WHOLE YEAR */
       TO_CHAR (START_WEEK_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') START_WEEK_DATE,
       TO_CHAR (END_WEEK_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') END_WEEK_DATE,
       (SELECT SUM (ONSITE_UPD_QTY)
          FROM DTL_ERC_UPD
         WHERE     UPD_DATE BETWEEN rs.START_WEEK_DATE AND rs.END_WEEK_DATE
               AND PROJECT_NAME IN (SELECT PROJECT_NAME
                                      FROM PROJECT
                                     WHERE PROJECT_NO = RS.JOB_NAME)) ONSITEQTY
from ( SELECT LEVEL WEEK_NUM_INCR,
              start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 START_WEEK_DATE,
              start_date + (LEVEL) * 7 END_WEEK_DATE,
              RS.JOB_NAME
       FROM (SELECT PS.PROJECT_START_DT start_date,
                      PS.JOB_NAME JOB_NAME,
                      PS.PROJECT_END_DT end_date
                 FROM PROJECT_SPAN PS
                WHERE PS.JOB_NAME = 'W-14026') RS
       CONNECT BY start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 < end_date ) rs
```

But anyways, ONSITEQTY would be 10, not 14, because the last week ends on 5th February at 00:00:00. And two rows of DTL_ERC_UPD have UPD_DATE with one additional minute. They don't fit in the last week.

Comment: THanks qualtgh... in this case IGGMILLHOUSE Doesnt count in the query because only covers SMSMILLHOUSE and SMSSUGARWHOUSE..

Comment: @KonzMama: yes, I see. IGGMILLHOUSE doesn't suit. February, 5th doesn't suit. The only two records that suit are SMSMILLHOUSE on 4th of February. It's 10 in sum. Is this what was expected?

Comment: yes its right but does this query conform the data changes? so that user only enter the PROJECT_START_DATE and PROJECT_END_DT from PROJECT_SPAN table and output should be dynamically changes as the user input more data inside the DTL_ERC_UPD

Comment: Yes, it's a slightly modified original query. Remove `with`-constructions, add a link to DTL_ERC_UPD and it will suit your environment as original query did.